# I need Apollo GraphQL to send back http responses

Tags: graphql, apollo, apollo-server

I'd like for the ability to have my express graphQL server to send back the HTTP status code along with the response to the client. At the moment, all I see is `data`, however, additional functionality based on the status code would be helpful.

I don't see anything here, unless I'm looking in the wrong place:

http://dev.apollodata.com/tools/graphql-server/setup.html

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. The response is already sent with a 200 status code. Do you want a separate status code for each request to the backend that was made to fulfill the query (there may be many)?

Comment: I know that the `response` within the network tab has the status code, however, the data that I actually get back from the GraphQL only contains the `data`. I'd like to also see this in the client side to do other forms of testing

Comment: @helfer I think what he is meaning is let's say you get a 404 not found error for a resource that doesn't exist. There isn't anyway to make this status code flow to your client. I have a similar example, I have a resolver for a rest API endpoint and it returns 404 not found if a resource doesn't exist, how would one buble this up?

Answer (score 0):

For Apollo Server 2.2.x and later, we can use plugins to custom the HTTP status code. Custom the HTTP status code in [willsendresponse](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/apollo-server/integrations/plugins/#willsendresponse) event handler. You can check the `errors` array and set the corresponding HTTP status code for different type of error.

E.g.

`server.ts`:

```js
import { ApolloServer, gql } from 'apollo-server';
import { ApolloServerPlugin } from 'apollo-server-plugin-base';

function customHTTPStatusPlugin(): ApolloServerPlugin {
  return {
    requestDidStart(requestContext) {
      return {
        willSendResponse({ errors, response }) {
          if (response && response.http) {
            if (errors) {
              response.data = undefined;
              response.http.status = 500;
            }
          }
        },
      };
    },
  };
}

const typeDefs = gql`
  type Query {
    hello: String
  }
`;
const resolvers = {
  Query: {
    hello() {
      throw new Error('something happened');
    },
  },
};

const server = new ApolloServer({ typeDefs, resolvers, plugins: [customHTTPStatusPlugin()] });
const port = 3000;
server.listen(port).then(({ url }) => console.log(`Server is ready at ${url}`));
```

The response:

```json
{
  "error": {
    "errors": [
      {
        "message": "something happened",
        "locations": [
          {
            "line": 2,
            "column": 3
          }
        ],
        "path": [
          "hello"
        ],
        "extensions": {
          "code": "INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR",
          "exception": {
            "stacktrace": [
              "Error: something happened",
              "    at hello (/Users/ldu020/workspace/github.com/mrdulin/apollo-graphql-tutorial/src/stackoverflow/40387508/server.ts:30:13)",
              "    at field.resolve (/Users/ldu020/workspace/github.com/mrdulin/apollo-graphql-tutorial/node_modules/apollo-server-express/node_modules/graphql-extensions/src/index.ts:274:18)",
              "    at field.resolve (/Users/ldu020/workspace/github.com/mrdulin/apollo-graphql-tutorial/node_modules/apollo-server-express/node_modules/apollo-server-core/src/utils/schemaInstrumentation.ts:103:18)",
              "    at resolveFieldValueOrError (/Users/ldu020/workspace/github.com/mrdulin/apollo-graphql-tutorial/node_modules/graphql/execution/execute.js:467:18)",
              "    at resolveField (/Users/ldu020/workspace/github.com/mrdulin/apollo-graphql-tutorial/node_modules/graphql/execution/execute.js:434:16)",
              "    at executeFields (/Users/ldu020/workspace/github.com/mrdulin/apollo-graphql-tutorial/node_modules/graphql/execution/execute.js:275:18)",
              "    at executeOperation (/Users/ldu020/workspace/github.com/mrdulin/apollo-graphql-tutorial/node_modules/graphql/execution/execute.js:219:122)",
              "    at executeImpl (/Users/ldu020/workspace/github.com/mrdulin/apollo-graphql-tutorial/node_modules/graphql/execution/execute.js:104:14)",
              "    at Object.execute (/Users/ldu020/workspace/github.com/mrdulin/apollo-graphql-tutorial/node_modules/graphql/execution/execute.js:64:35)",
              "    at /Users/ldu020/workspace/github.com/mrdulin/apollo-graphql-tutorial/node_modules/apollo-server-express/node_modules/apollo-server-core/src/requestPipeline.ts:548:22"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

You will also get the HTTP status code - `500 Internal Server Error` at the client-side.